# Create a Simple Registration and Login System with C

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

After some help if possible.

I have a class project that requires building a simple login and registration system, which also needs input validation for the password and username meeting length/character requirements. 
I am an absolute beginner and really struggling. I haven't even got around to making the validation as the code I have so far can't compile. I understand it might look messy, but I do struggle with c programming.

Here is the error

```
login2.c: In function ‘login’:
login2.c:11:15: error: storage size of ‘l’ isn’t known
   11 |  struct login l;
```

Any help would be absolutely amazing. 
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

login()
{
    char username[30],password[20];
    FILE *log;
    log=fopen("login.txt","r");
    struct login l;

    printf("\nPlease Enter your login credentials below\n\n");
    printf("Username:  ");
    fgets(username, 30, stdin);
    printf("\nPassword: ");
    printf("\n");
    fgets(password, 20, stdin);

    while(fread(&l,sizeof(l),1,log))
        {
        if(strcmp(username,l.username)==0 && strcmp(password,l.password)==0)

            {   
                printf("\nSuccessful Login\n");
            }
        else 
            {
                printf("\nIncorrect Login Details\nPlease enter the correct credentials\n");
            }
}

fclose(log);

}

struct login
{
    char fname[30];
    char lname[30];
    char username[30];
    char password[20];
}


registration()
{
    char firstname[15];
    FILE *log;
    log=fopen("login.txt","w");
    struct login l;

    printf("\nWelcome to your online course provider. We need to enter some details for registration.\n\n");
    printf("\nEnter First Name:\n");
    scanf("%c",l.fname);
    printf("\nEnter Surname:\n");
    scanf("%c",l.lname);

    printf("Thank you.\nNow please choose a username and password as credentials for system login.\nEnsure the username is no more than 30 characters long.\nEnsure your password is at least 8 characters long and contains lowercase, uppercase, numerical and special character values.\n"); 

    printf("\nEnter Username:\n");
    scanf("%c",l.username);
    printf("\nEnter Password:\n");
    scanf("%c",l.password);


    fwrite(&l,sizeof(l),1,log);
    fclose(log);

    printf("\nConfirming details...\n...\nWelcome, %c!\n\n",firstname);
    printf("\nRegistration Successful!\n");
    printf("Press any key to continue...");
        getchar();
    system("CLS");
    login();
}


int main()
{
    int option;

    printf("Press '1' to Register\nPress '2' to Login\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&option);

    if(option == 1)
        {
            system("CLS");
            registration();
        }

    else if(option == 2)
        {
            system("CLS");
            login();
        }
}
```

Comment: If you got any errors at compiling, please share them with us.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). That is, ask about a specific error or ask a more specific question than "please help". For example, you say there are compile errors so show those errors.

Comment: And what is your actual issue? The creation of the validation process only? Or is it something else too? Learn to be focused, so that we can help you in the best possible way.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. I have made changes to show error. I am unsure if the overall syntax was okay too

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: BTW: `fopen` can fail, for example because the file does not exist. What do you think happens if `fopen` fails? Read the documentation closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler reads the file from top to bottom. This means the compiler don´t "know" what `struct login` is at the definition of `l`. The definition of the structure `login` needs either to be set before the definition of `l` or you need to do a forward declaration of the structure `login`.

Next thing is that the definition of `login` misses a `;` at the end of it.

Also the definition head of `login()` shall be `void login (void)` and `registration()` shall be `void registration (void)`.

Furthermore you use `%c` instead of `%s` when printing or input a string:

```
    printf("\nEnter First Name:\n");
    scanf("%c",l.fname);
```

or

```
printf("\nConfirming details...\n...\nWelcome, %c!\n\n",firstname);
```

Also ever check if the opening of a file was successful by checking the pointer returned for a null pointer:

```
log = fopen("login.txt","r");
if (log == NULL)
{
    fputs("Error at opening File!", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

---

As a side note you´re working code will probably skip:

```
fgets(username, 30, stdin);
```

in `login()` because you have the `scanf()` statement of:

```
scanf("%d",&option);
```

in the control flow before which leaves a newline character in `stdin`. This newline character is fetched by the `fgets()` call. Place a `getchar()` after `scanf()`.

---

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct login                           // before the first use of `l`.
{
    char fname[30];
    char lname[30];
    char username[30];
    char password[20];
};

void login (void);
void registration (void);

int main (void)
{
    int option;

    printf("Press '1' to Register\nPress '2' to Login\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&option);

    getchar();           // catching newline.

    if(option == 1)
        {
            system("CLS");
            registration();
        }

    else if(option == 2)
        {
            system("CLS");
            login();
        }
}

void login (void)
{
    char username[30],password[20];
    FILE *log;

    log = fopen("login.txt","r");
    if (log == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Error at opening File!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct login l;

    printf("\nPlease Enter your login credentials below\n\n");
    printf("Username:  ");
    fgets(username, 30, stdin);
    printf("\nPassword: ");
    printf("\n");
    fgets(password, 20, stdin);

    while(fread(&l,sizeof(l),1,log))
        {
        if(strcmp(username,l.username)==0 && strcmp(password,l.password)==0)

            {   
                printf("\nSuccessful Login\n");
            }
        else 
            {
                printf("\nIncorrect Login Details\nPlease enter the correct credentials\n");
            }
        }

    fclose(log);

    return;
}




void registration(void)
{
    char firstname[15];
    FILE *log;

    log=fopen("login.txt","w");
    if (log == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Error at opening File!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }


    struct login l;

    printf("\nWelcome to your online course provider. We need to enter some details for registration.\n\n");
    printf("\nEnter First Name:\n");
    scanf("%c",l.fname);
    printf("\nEnter Surname:\n");
    scanf("%s",l.lname);

    printf("Thank you.\nNow please choose a username and password as credentials for system login.\nEnsure the username is no more than 30 characters long.\nEnsure your password is at least 8 characters long and contains lowercase, uppercase, numerical and special character values.\n"); 

    printf("\nEnter Username:\n");
    scanf("%s",l.username);
    printf("\nEnter Password:\n");
    scanf("%s",l.password);


    fwrite(&l,sizeof(l),1,log);
    fclose(log);

    printf("\nConfirming details...\n...\nWelcome, %s!\n\n",firstname);
    printf("\nRegistration Successful!\n");
    printf("Press any key to continue...");
        getchar();
    system("CLS");
    login();
}
```